# mysql 4 way join returning null for all fields

Tags: mysql

I am building a sql query where I am
1) creating a group_concat which returns json if a value is not null
2) joining the one table (handle) to two different tables.

I'm having two problems with the query
1) when I have a result that 'should' fail with 0 rows returned, I am getting a single row where all fields are null
2) when I have a `scene` which has no activities, I end up with a `JSON_OBJECT` where all the fields are null

```
    SELECT h.name as name, s.*, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(
            'activityId', a.id,
            'name', ah.name,
            'settings', a.settings,
        ) SEPARATOR ',') as activities
        FROM scene AS s
        INNER JOIN user AS h ON s.uid = h.id
        LEFT JOIN scene_activities AS sa ON sa.sid = s.id
        LEFT JOIN activity AS a ON sa.aid = a.id
        LEFT JOIN user AS ah ON a.uid = ah.id
  WHERE s.scene_id = ?
```

How can I set the above field so that empty sets of the `Scene` are not returned or empty sets of the `JSON_OBJECT` are null.

Comment: Try with inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require all attributes in your json to have non-null values, don't use `left` joins (which returns nulls if there's no matching row) and put a condition on the value in the joined row too:

```
SELECT h.name as name, s.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(
        'activityId', a.id,
        'name', ah.name,
        'settings', a.settings,
    ) SEPARATOR ',') as activities
FROM scene AS s
JOIN user AS h ON s.uid = h.id
JOIN scene_activities AS sa ON sa.sid = s.id
JOIN activity AS a ON sa.aid = a.id
    and a.settings is not null
JOIN user AS ah ON a.uid = ah.id
    and ah.name is not null
WHERE s.scene_id = ?
```

Comment: That solved the JSON issue, but I'm still having trouble getting empty results from the main query. Any advice on that one? `

Comment: actually I got it, wrapped the query in `SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) as q WHERE q.name IS NOT NULL)`